# How to put 1st dimension along 3rd in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, reshape

Suppose I have a matrix

```
A=[1 2 3]
```

which is row matrix. Not I want to do it "page" matrix, i.e. align elements along 3rd dimension.

I noticed, that the following

```
A=permute(A,[3 1 2])
```

works, while the following

```
A=permute(A,[3 2 1])
```

does not.

Why?

Comment: It works for me as in not throwing errors. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Just as a reminder: if you think that one of the answers fits your question, please chose it, or at least up-vote it. For some of us the points are important -- because that gives them "budget" to post bounties for hard problems, and the points are site's "currency" to pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. If I'm right you'd like your matrix to become B = [0,0,1;0,0,2; 0,0,3].

This can be done easily with the transpose function by typing:

```
 B(:,:,3)=A'
```

Instead of using the permute function which is a generalization of transpose. Also, your operation might not "work" because permute is an operation that affects the dimension of the array, and not of its elements

Comment: 1. The result from `B(:,:,3)=A'` is not `B = [0,0,1;0,0,2; 0,0,3]`. 2. I don't think neither is the result OP wants. 3. It's better to use `A.'` for transpose. This would give the correct result: `B(1,1,:) = A`. Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the size of `A` is `[1 3]`, not `[3 1]`. As CST-Link points out, this is equivalent with `[1 3 1 1]` etc., since the singleton dimensions are removed.

```
size(A,1) = 1
size(A,2) = 3   <-- You want this to be the third dimension
size(A,3) = 1
```

Now, what you want to do is align the second dimension (the one telling you how many columns you have) to the third dimension (the one telling you how many slices you have).

When you use [`permute`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), you specify the order you want the original dimensions to occur. I.e. if you do `permute(A, [2 1])` for a vector, you will transpose it. The second dimension is now the first and vice versa. You want the second dimemsion to be the third, and keep the first dimension constant, so:

```
permute(A, [1 3 2])
```

If you do:

```
permute(A, [3 2 1])
```

you will take the third dimension to be the first (`size(A,1) = 1`), the second dimension (`size(A,2) = 3`) will be the second (i.e. it is not changed), and the first dimension is the third. Thus, the only dimensions that change are the first and third. These are both 1 to begin with, so nothing has changed.

Note that you can also use [`shiftdim`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) in this particular case:

```
shiftdim(A,-1)
```